# How to cast DependencyObject as FileInfo in PropertyChangedCallback

Tags: c#, wpf, dependencyobject

I have a `FileInfo` type DependencyProperty and in the `PropertyChangedCallback`, I can't cast the `DependencyObject` to `FileInfo` type.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetFileProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TargetFile", typeof(System.IO.FileInfo), typeof(FileSelectGroup), new PropertyMetadata(propertyChangedCallback: new PropertyChangedCallback());

    private PropertyChangedCallback OnTargetFileChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var f = (System.IO.FileInfo)d; // THIS LINE GIVES ERROR BELOW
    }
```

Error is:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' to 'System.IO.FileInfo'

I thought maybe I was missing something obvious (I probably am) but [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35613584/2043621) seem to agree I'm doing roughly the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` refers to the control where the dependency property is defined, i.e. the `FileSelectGroup`.

You should be able to cast `e.NewValue` to a `System.IO.FileInfo` to get the new value of the dependency property:

```
private PropertyChangedCallback OnTargetFileChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var f = e.NewValue as System.IO.FileInfo;
    if (f != null)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could cast `d` to `FileSelectGroup` and access the `TargetFile` property of the control:

```
private PropertyChangedCallback OnTargetFileChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = d as FileSelectGroup;
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo f = ctrl.TargetFile;
        if (f != null)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, yes that works (the `e.NewValue` version is what I tested just now) but do you know why conversion to FileInfo fails but other types apparently work fine?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Obviously you cannot cast anything that isn't a FileInfo to a FileInfo. And d is not a FileInfo in this case.